# R _ Make combinations of multiple dataframes & columns of different size

Tags: r, combinations

My first question here...

I have 2 dataframes, both with a different number of rows.
The first one has 3 columns, the second one has 1 column.

I want to make all combinations of values from the 1st column of the 1st dataframe with values in the 1st (and only) column of the second dataframe, and values of 2nd column of 1st dataframe with values in 1st (and only) column of second dataframe, and so on...
I assume the result will be a one-column dataframe (?).

Something like this:

[image]

Attempts with combn did not help me yet...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not fully what you want, but provides a starting point. Providing your first dataframe is called `df` and the other one (with one column) `df2`

```
#make data long using tidyr
df_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = c("loc1", "loc2", "loc3"))

#cartesian join with codes column
CJ(df_long$value, df2)
```